# Unset batch of keys in an array from another array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] => qst
    [1] => insert_question_note
    [2] => preview_ans
    [3] => _preview
    [4] => view_structure_answer_preview
    [5] => index
}
```

I need to unset the array keys based on elements in

```
$array_elements_to_be_remove = array('qst','_preview'); // or any string start with '_'
```

I tried to use:

```
$array_key = array_search('qst', $array);
unset($array[$array_key]);

$array_key_1 = array_search('_preview', $array);
unset($array[$array_key_1]);
```

Is there any other better ways to search batch of elements in **$array** ?

I expect that if I can use array search like this:

```
$array_keys_to_be_unset = array_search($array_elements_to_be_remove, $array);
```

I found a way to search the string if it is start with '_' as below:

```
substr('_thestring', 0, 1)
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$array = Array(
    0 => 'qst',
    1 => 'insert_question_note',
    2 => 'preview_ans',
    3 => '_preview',
    4 => 'view_structure_answer_preview',
    5 => 'index'
);

$array_elements_to_be_remove = array('qst', '_preview'); // or any string start with '_'
$new_array = array_filter($array, function($item)use($array_elements_to_be_remove) {
    if (in_array($item, $array_elements_to_be_remove) || $item[0] == '_')
        return false; // if value in $array_elements_to_be_remove or any string start with '_'
    else
        return true;
});
var_dump($new_array);
```

Comment: Excellent! Millions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php build function array_diff:

```
$arr=array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

[Refer this php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: Thanks, how about the string started with '_'?

Comment: I meant, to search automatically the elements contained in $array1 and push to array2